# Оптимизация скрипта Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <! -- 
    var Mass1, Mass2, Mass3, Mass4, Mass5, Mass6, Mass7, Mass8, Mass9, Mass10, Mass11, Mass12, Mass13, Mass14, Mass15, Mass16;
    Mass1 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass2 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass3 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass4 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass5 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass6 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass7 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    Mass8 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
    for (var e = 1; e < 64; e++) {
        for (var d = 1; d < 64; d++) {
            for (var c = 1; c < 64; c++) {
                for (var b = 1; b < 64; b++) {
                    for (var a = 1; a < 64; a++) {
                        for (var l = 1; l < 64; l++) {
                            for (var i = 1; i < 64; i++) {
                                for (var n = 1; n < 64; n++) {
                                    document.write("" + Mass1[i] + Mass2[n] + Mass3[l] + Mass4[a] + Mass5[b] + Mass6[c] + Mass7[d] + Mass8[e] + "<br>");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //-->

</script>
```

Вот этот скрипт Google Chrome не загружает (сначала покинуть или дождаться загрузки, загружает, а потом страницу не удалось открыть), помогите облегчить скрипт, может кто на другом языке программирования напишет, но чтобы функция такой же осталась. Скрипт рабочий, на меньшем колличестве массивов работает прекрасно!

Comment: Смотреть мой вопрос Перебор JavascriptДля получения скрипта(массивов 16, в массиве переменных 64(в начале пробел, в конце пробел, цифры, английские буквы в верхнем и нижнем регистрах.

Comment: О боги - какой смысл в этом скрипте? зачем тупо копировать одну и ту же инфу 16 раз по разным массивам? ужс...<br>
Тут скорее мозг ваш оптимизировать надо а скрипт писать "с чистого листа"<br>
Вы написали что GoogleChrome не загружает... А IE типа грузит? xDDD

Comment: Вот из-за незнания языка, наверное, приходит мысль в голову, что программирование очень сложная штука)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не сможете выполнить этот скрипт, т.к. для вывода такого кол-ва информации минимум надо:
**64^8 = 256 ПЕТАбайт памяти**

Не смотря на абсурдность результата выполнения, лучше так:

```
var str = " 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ",
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h,
    m = 64;
for ( e = 1; e < m; e++) {
  for ( d = 1; d < m; d++) {
    for ( c = 1; c < m; c++) {
      for ( b = 1; b < m; b++) {
        for ( a = 1; a < m; a++) {
          for ( l = 1; l < m; l++) {
            for ( i = 1; i < m; i++) {
              for ( n = 1; n < m; n++) {
                document.write(
                  str[a] + str[b] + str[c] + str[d] + 
                  str[e] + str[f] + str[g] + str[h] + '<br>'
                );
} } } } } } } }
```

Comment: Я считаю, что этот ответ надо засчитать как правильный=))

Comment: В таком случае у вас пустой строки не будет, как мне кажется.

Comment: @shurik, будет) посмотрите внимательнее

Comment: а, пробел, ну впринципе будет выглядеть также, да согласен, проглядел

Comment: @shurik, не факт что проглядели, просто пробелы добавились за минуту до вашего комментария)

Comment: А у вас есть 256 петабайт памяти?)))

Comment: А разве `str[i]` работает? Это же не php - тут `charAt(i)` нужен.

Comment: Работает, в Chrome точно.

Answer (score 1):

Кхе-кхе.

Тупой перебор всех возможных комбинаций для строки из 8ми символов из возможных 64х символов

нууу, это мягко говоря долго:

```
   n!        64!
-------- = -------- = 178462987637760 вариантов
(n - k)!    (64-8)!
```

Облегчить его в плане выполнения - не реально. А вот в плане кода - пожалуй.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <! -- 
    var alphabet = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D" , "E" , "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",  "a", "b", "c", "d" , "e" , "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];

function calc(a, depth, str) {
    if (depth == 7) {
        document.write(str + '<br/>');
        return ;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        calc(a, depth + 1, str + a[i]);
    }
}

calc(alphabet, 0, '');
</script>
```

Я не проверял, но поидее должно работать (ну как работать, во всяком случае оно делает тоже, что и ваш код. Уменьшите число 7 до 3х хотя бы, что бы получить результат)

Comment: Уменьшите число 7 до 3х хотя бы, что бы получить результат

вы это делали ?